# String concatenation in gawk produces an unexpected result

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm trying to write a simple script in awk but I'm getting strange result and can't understand why. Cannot find any clue in the manual or web:

Here's the input file:

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=14,expires=4,avg_ttl=454226332
```

Here's the command

```
gawk -F : '/^db/ { split($2, keys, ","); for(i in keys) { k = gensub("=", ":", "g", keys[i]); print ("redis." $1 "." k "Z")} }'
```

Here's the result:

```
redis.db0.keys:14Z
redis.db0.expires:4Z
Zedis.db0.avg_ttl:454226332
```

Why doesn't the last line have a "Z" at the end? Doesn't matter if I use gawk or awk (Mac).

Expected result would be:

```
redis.db0.keys:14Z
redis.db0.expires:4Z
redis.db0.avg_ttl:454226332Z
```

Comment: what is your expected result? Note you are pasting a long command and asking why it produces something without giving any hint on what it is _supposed_ to do. Please [edit] your question to include those relevant details.

Comment: also, since you are using `split()` twice, consider setting a different FS to get rid of one of them.

Comment: My `GNU Awk 4.1.3` returns the expected result normally. Maybe you have some bad endings? Do `cat -vet file` to see if something is broken in the file.

Comment: @fedorqui oh boy, that's it! The text file came from another command which strangely produced lines with CRLF.

Comment: Nice! :) So I am voting to close the question as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks mate for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file has a control-M at the end of each line, use `cat -v` to see it and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.

This has GOT to be by FAR the most common problem we get questions about.... wish there was some "run `cat -v file` and look for `^M`s before posting" requirement we could impose on questions!

Comment: yeah, but in cases like that I would expect consistency - why not all of the lines looked the same? :-/

Comment: Don't confuse output lines with input lines. It's your INPUT lines that end in control-Ms so your input is actually `db0:keys=14,expires=4,avg_ttl=454226332<controlM>` - there's just 1 control-M and it's at the end of `avg_ttl=454226332<controlM>`, not at the end of the other 2 fields, so it only appears in the 3rd output line because it's only present in the 3rd input field.